# Unable to perform pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv's I want to perform outer join based on index (index is a combination of 2 columns)

```
frame1=pd.read_csv("Gamesa_G114 (Carlos Almeida)1.csv",index_col=['Dispositivo','Fecha'],sep=',',dtype='str')
frame2=pd.read_csv("Gamesa_G114 (Carlos Almeida).csv",index_col=['Dispositivo','Fecha'],sep=',',dtype='str')
```

Snapshot of both the frames
[image]

Now I am performing outer join

```
frame=pd.merge(left=frame1,right=frame2,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='outer',suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
```

But it gives an error

> > TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()

For stacktrace of error http://pastebin.com/eWYfnMRT

Why it is saying **TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()** if I have already specified **dtype='str'** while reading csv

I have performed merge various times but never I have encountered this problem of type error.

Post edit
 Frame info
[image]

Comment: What is `frame1.info()` and `frame2.info()` ?

Comment: Maybe need convert to `str` by `astype` - `frame1 = frame1.astype(str)`
and `frame2 = frame2.astype(str)`

Comment: @jezrael it didn't help

Comment: I have added frame info

Comment: interesting, it seems nice. and what about `print (frame1.index.get_level_values(1).dtype)` and `print (frame2.index.get_level_values(1).dtype)` ?

Comment: both are object

Comment: so it looks like bug, what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())`. Last version is `0.19.2`

Comment: pandas version 0.19.1

Comment: So I dnot understand. But maybe is possible use `concat` `frame=pd.concat([rame1,right=frame2])`

Comment: In pandas 0.19.2 this problem still exist

Comment: ara data condidental?

Answer (score 0):

This may be not a solution to your answer but a comment on dtype

You need to pass a dictionary in dtype E.g. `{‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}` instead of the String.

I am using answer space to write this because i don't have enough permission to comment.